# How do keep displaying old image while loading new image?

Tags: image, flutter, networkx

I am new to Flutter development.

I am working on image display system.

Using NetworImage to display images.

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(url), fit: BoxFit.contain)),
    )
```

When I have to display next image, what i do is change the url.
This works fine, but when i do this old image gets removed till new image is loaded.

Is there a way to keep showing the old image until new image get loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked this :

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

You can give a placeholder of you own as a widget Let me know if it works

Comment: the image from the placeholder is also coming from an url. But it is previously downloaded image. for the placeholder if i use something like NetworkImage will it download it again ?

Comment: Placeholder can be used in two ways ,when you cannot get the image or also you can use it as a loader like if image gets loaded then it will show show the network image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the popular package called as [Cached Network Image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image). What you can do is to use it's placeholder to show the older image, in place of `ProgressIndicator`.

> `placeholder` helps you show the `Widget` until your image is loaded

Pass your old URL to the placeholder until the new image is loaded

```
     CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => // use your widget here to show the older image,
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     )
```

Comment: the image from the placeholder is also coming from an url. But it is previously downloaded image. for the placeholder if i use something like NetworkImage will it download it again ?

Comment: Yes, for your `placeholder`, you are absolutely free to use any `widget`. Go ahead and try it out @Janaka. Also, keep a track of the older URL, so that, you can pass it to the Widget when needed.

Comment: Will it download the same image again or pick it from say cache ?

Comment: @Janaka The Cached Network Image, will cache the image, when there is no network. For placeholder if you provide a `NetworkImage()`, it will just work like `NetworkImage()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to wait for the next image while still displaying the current image..

```
import 'dart:async';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String firstURL = 'https://example_first_url';
  String nextURL = 'https://example_next_url';
  Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();
  NetworkImage nextNetworkImg;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: nextNetworkImg ?? NetworkImage(firstURL),
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Next'),
          onPressed: onNext,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onNext() async {
    nextNetworkImg = await getNwImage(nextURL);
    setState((){});
  }

  Future<NetworkImage> getNwImage(String url) async {
    NetworkImage networkImg = NetworkImage(url);
    networkImg
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info);
    }));
    await completer.future;
    return networkImg;
  }
}
```